# Using a script to load an engine in Openssl and use it to sign a file

Tags: bash, openssl

I want to sign a file using the private key on a smartcard.
Using these commands:

```
openssl
engine -t dynamic -pre SO_PATH:/usr/lib/engines/engine_pkcs11.so -pre ID:pkcs11 -pre LIST_ADD:1 -pre LOAD -pre MODULE_PATH:/usr/lib/opensc-pkcs11.so
dgst -engine pkcs11 -sign slot_0-id_1 -keyform engine -sha256 -out signature.bin textToSign.txt
quit
```

it works perfectly in the terminal.
I would like to write a little script which signs a file using these commands.
It looks like this:

```
#/bin/bash
openssl engine -t dynamic -pre SO_PATH:/usr/lib/engines/engine_pkcs11.so -pre ID:pkcs11 -pre LIST_ADD:1 -pre LOAD -pre MODULE_PATH:/usr/lib/opensc-pkcs11.so
openssl dgst -engine pkcs11 -sign slot_0-id_1 -keyform engine -sha256 -out signature.bin textToSign.txt
```

The problem is, that the engine is not present for use in the dgst - command.
Is it possible to start a openssl - session in a script and execute these two commands?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the 'here document' bash functionality `<<` in your script:

```
#/bin/bash
openssl << EOT
engine -t dynamic -pre SO_PATH:/usr/lib/engines/engine_pkcs11.so -pre ID:pkcs11 -pre LIST_ADD:1 -pre LOAD -pre MODULE_PATH:/usr/lib/opensc-pkcs11.so
dgst -engine pkcs11 -sign slot_0-id_1 -keyform engine -sha256 -out signature.bin textToSign.txt
quit
EOT
```

Comment: Unfortunately, OpenSSL 3.0 removes the interactive mode, so I'm in search of alternatives:

commit eca471391378139f76a7d1229b6a5a1dcc4b5603
Author: Richard Levitte <levitte@openssl.org>
Date:   Wed Jun 3 10:49:50 2020 +0200

    APPS: Drop interactive mode in the 'openssl' program

    This mode is severely untested and unmaintained, is seems not to be
    used very much.

    Closes #4679
    Closes #6292

    Reviewed-by: Paul Dale <paul.dale@oracle.com>
    Reviewed-by: Tomas Mraz <tmraz@fedoraproject.org>
    (Merged from https://github.com/openssl/openssl/pull/12023)